# Permission denied to create /opt/ejson/keys

Tags: simplejson

I'm trying to use Shopify ejson https://github.com/Shopify/ejson

When I run:

`mkdir -p /opt/ejson/keys`

I get permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this Github issue: https://github.com/Shopify/ejson/issues/80

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/ejson`

But would rather not have to use sudo